# Tableau Custom Format

Tags: tableau-api

This question has been Answered.
 aamir zamir
Heat Mapper
aamir zamir Jul 22, 2013 12:04 AM
I am getting custom format error in tableau , i have done some date calculation after that I want to format it from custom formatting , but I am getting error like

```
filled date           order date            Measure Values  dd:hh:mm:ss 
                                                            (custom format )
12/7/2012 8:30:00 PM  12/7/2012 4:30:00 PM  0.166666667     30:04:00:00
```

but I want it to show

```
filled date           order date            Measure Values  dd:hh:mm:ss 
                                                            (custom format )
12/7/2012 8:30:00 PM  12/7/2012 4:30:00 PM  0.166666667     0:04:00:00
```

in case of more than 1.166667 its giving me correct value like 01:04:00:00

i cant understand error , can you guide me please..

Can you guide me how to write calculation for custom format , I have separate day measure , we can write that

```
if day =0 then 
    sum (Value ) in hh:mm:ss format 
else 
    sum (value) in dd:hh:mm:ss format.
```

Comment: it is very difficult to understand your question. I suggest creating a packaged workbook that demonstrates the problem and posting it on Tableau's forums at http://community.tableausoftware.com/community/forums

Comment: After improve question format I have not understand nothing about you are asking. I also vote to close.

Comment: Are you trying to show the time taken to fulfil an order ie the difference between `filled date` and `order date`?

Comment: This is a reposting of a question that was asked and answered on the Tableau Software Community Support site.  http://community.tableausoftware.com/thread/129184?start=0&tstart=0